# how can I show all the total of all purchases by ad type using self join

Tags: sql

Im trying to sum by ad type per column so im using self join but however there is no value returened

```
SELECT
a.campaign,
a.campaign_id,
SUM(a.purchases) AS sponsored_products,
SUM(b.purchases) AS sponsored_display,
SUM(c.purchases) AS sponsored_brands,
SUM(d.purchases) AS dsp

FROM 
  amazon_attributed_events_by_traffic_time a
     JOIN amazon_attributed_events_by_traffic_time b
      ON  b.campaign_id= a.campaign_id and
        b.ad_product_type = 'sponsored_display'
      JOIN amazon_attributed_events_by_traffic_time c
      ON  c.campaign_id= a.campaign_id and
     c.ad_product_type = 'sponsored_brands'
      JOIN amazon_attributed_events_by_traffic_time d
      ON  d.campaign_id= a.campaign_id and
      d.ad_product_type is null
Where
a.ad_product_type = 'sponsored_products'
group by a.campaign, a.campaign_id, a.ad_product_type,  b.ad_product_type, c.ad_product_type ,d.ad_product_type
```

[image]

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. Please (re)tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS. Tagging conflicting products does not help us help you.#

Comment: Also I suggest a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). "A" is for "**a**mazon_attributed_events_by_traffic_time", "b" is for "amazon_attributed_events_**b**y_traffic_time", "c" for "amazon_attributed_events_by_traffi**c**_time" isn't helpful to any one.

Comment: You've tagged [[tag:rdbms]], not the RDBMS you are using... Adding that tag is like responding with "car" when asked what car do you drive. We know you are using an RDBMS, but you need to tell us *what* RDBMS.

Comment: Please don't use images - as the information they contain is not copyable by anyone wanting to try out a solution. Please also update your code with sample data for your source table and the result you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try something like this (Not tested..)

```
SELECT
    campaign,
    campaign_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ad_product_type = 'sponsored_products' THEN purchases ELSE 0 END) AS sponsored_products,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ad_product_type = 'sponsored_display' THEN purchases ELSE 0 END) AS sponsored_display,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ad_product_type = 'sponsored_brands' THEN purchases ELSE 0 END) AS sponsored_brands,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ad_product_type IS NULL THEN purchases ELSE 0 END) AS dsp
FROM
    amazon_attributed_events_by_traffic_time
WHERE
    ad_product_type IN ('sponsored_products', 'sponsored_display', 'sponsored_brands') OR ad_product_type IS NULL
GROUP BY
    campaign, campaign_id;
```